# Android - Migrating to Room Database

Tags: android, database, android-room, android-architecture-components

I need to migrate from Sqlite database to room in my application, but before migrating i have some doubts regrading room database i have searched through many sites but i have not satisfied with the solution.

1. My table schema will be changing frequently through API calls, is it possible in room ?
2. We need entities to map Column Name with entity properties, Since my table schema changes frequently how do i create the entity ?
3. Is it possible to map the multiple columns to single field property in entity, like say 
   Table A has three columns COL_A,COL_B,COL_C

```
@Entity
class TableA{
  @ColumnInfo("COL_A")
  val columnA : String

  @ColumnInfo("COL_B,COL_C")
  val columns : Map<String,String>
}
```

Is it possible to create entity like above in room?
Can anyone clear the above doubts ?

Comment: It sounds like you should be using a NoSql style database (such as LevelDB) - sqlite does not seem to be the right tool for such a dynamic table structure.

Comment: Room is not a database, it's a persistence abstraction layer for SQLite.